# Excel macro type mismatch error exiting for loop

Tags: vba, types, mismatch

I am getting a type mismatch error when the macro exits the For loop.  I have no clue why though and would appreciate any help I can get.  I did try searching for this issue but none of the suggestions apply in my case.

```
    Option Explicit
        Dim MODULE_NAME() As String
        Dim Counter As Long
        Dim i As Long
1210                            For Counter = i To CLng(i + CLng(CLng(UBound(MODULE_NAME)) Mod 127))
1220                                Call MacroLineNum(Counter, MODULE_NAME, TotalLines)
1230                                If Counter Mod UpdateFreq = 0 Then
1240                                    '**Save the file
1250                                    With gloMacroWorkbook
1260                                        If Not .ReadOnly Then
1270                                            .Save
1280                                        Else
1290                                            .Saved = False
1300                                        End If
1310                                    End With
1320                                    LockWindowUpdate 0&
1330                                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1340                                    '   Update the status bar.
1350                                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1360                                    Call subStatusBarUpdater("Still updating the line numbers in the modules.  " & Counter & " of " & UBound(MODULE_NAME) & " processed....")
1370                                    If VBEHwnd Then
1380                                        LockWindowUpdate VBEHwnd
1390                                    End If
1400                                End If
1410                                If Counter = UBound(MODULE_NAME) Then
1420                                    MsgBox "Exiting for loop."
1430                                End If
1440                            Next Counter
1450                            MsgBox "Saving file"
```

My code reaches line 1420, but not line 1450.  I even added type conversion function 'CLng' to 1210, but nothing seems to help.  Between line 1420 and 1450, I always get 'Type Mismatch' error with no details of where and why.

The MODULE_NAME() array is a dynamic array of 159 string entries.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `MacroLineNum` do?

Comment: @Mat'sMug it's in jumps of 10, so it's 145 :)

Comment: @A A  it seems you are NOT exiting the `For` loop, add a `MsgBox` after line 1430 (before `Next Counter`) and write `MsgBox "Counter is : " & Counter`

Comment: Is `i` assigned anything before entering the loop? If it's 0, then the for loop goes `For Counter = 0 To 31`, which makes the condition `If Counter = UBound(MODULE_NAME)` quite unlikely to ever be `True`. Can you de-spaghettify your code a bit and try to reproduce the same problem with a [mcve]?

Comment: @Comintern Function MacroLineNum() is not the problem.  It basically puts numbers on the lines of code.  That function is processing correctly. and is not generating any errors.

Comment: @Shai Rado Lines 1410-1430 were added for debug purposes.  They all execute fine.  Per your suggestion I added another message box before line 1430 and that executes fine.  For some reason, it's failing only on line 1440 ONLY when exiting the loop.  It works fine at all other times, i.e. it iterates through the loop without issues.

Comment: Do you do anything with the `Counter` in `Function MacroLineNum()`? You're passing it a reference and ***I*** don't have enough information to rule it out.

Comment: @Mat's Mug thanks for the catch.  I forgot to mention the value of 'i' in my question.  'i' is set to 128 in this example. I'll try and see if I can post a full code set that is actually generating problems but is 'Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable'.

Comment: Include all your variable declarations and indicate what scope they're in.

Comment: @Comintern Counter is passed ByVal to MacroLineNum().  Here is the exact function declaration for that function:-  Sub MacroLineNum(ByVal Counter As Long, ByRef MODULE_NAME() As String, ByRef TotalLines As Long)

Comment: @Comintern You may have been right.  While creating the code set for your review, I have discovered that even though I only pass Counter by value to MacroLineNum, there seems to be some interaction between the the calling and called function.  When I comment out line 1220 in above code, everything works, but as soon as I uncomment that line, it breaks.

Comment: I'm not horribly surprised - that's literally the only thing that could have caused a type mismatch on a `Next` statement. If you want to edit in the code for the `MacroLineNum` function, I'd take a look.

Comment: Does the `MacroLineNum` function modify the code (e.g. change the line number) that is calling it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue completely by following some simple steps.  I don't know why, but this works.  I had only added the CLng calls as I couldn't get it to work earlier.

```
Option Explicit
    Dim MODULE_NAME() As String
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
1200                            k = i + (UBound(MODULE_NAME) Mod 127)
1210                            For Counter = i To k
1230                                Call MacroLineNum(Counter, MODULE_NAME, TotalLines)
1240                                If Counter Mod UpdateFreq = 0 Then
1250                                    '**Save the file
1260                                    With gloMacroWorkbook
1270                                        If Not .ReadOnly Then
1280                                            .Save
1290                                        Else
1300                                            .Saved = False
1310                                        End If
1320                                    End With
1330                                    LockWindowUpdate 0&
1340                                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1350                                    '   Update the status bar.
1360                                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1370                                    Call subStatusBarUpdater("Still updating the line numbers in the modules.  " & Counter & " of " & UBound(MODULE_NAME) & " processed....")
1380                                    If VBEHwnd Then
1390                                        LockWindowUpdate VBEHwnd
1400                                    End If
1410                                End If
1420                                If Counter = UBound(MODULE_NAME) Then
1430                                    MsgBox "Exiting for loop."
1440                                End If
1450                            Next Counter
1460                            MsgBox "Saving file"
```

Thanks everyone for you help and quick responses.  Although I would like to get to the bottom of this, creating the test code as requested is proving to be a bit tougher since I have too many interconnected function calls etc. that I need to stub out and provide for test code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, exactly what motivates having 1980's line numbers in VBA code?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, exactly what *justifies* having 1980's line numbers in VBA code?

Comment: FWIW if line numbers are ever used, e.g. `On Error GoTo 1590`, then re-numbering them can introduce nasty hard-to-find bugs. VBA hasn't needed line numbers for anything other than porting old legacy QBASIC code; they're reasonably harmful in new code, if only for the readability hit.

Comment: I am not using line numbers in the GoTo statements.  These are used by my custom error handler which reports the Erl, which, as you know, requires line numbers.  I have 35K+ lines in my macros with 159 separate modules.  This is the only way for me to be able to debug this code remotely.  I will be posting my macro to number/renumber and indent the lines automatically.  You may or may not find it useful.